# Cannot resolve Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android, service, permissions, gps, manifest

When adding permissions to my manifest file, the below xml works.

```
 <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

However, this xml doesn't work.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Which one am I supposed to be using? If it's the first one, why wouldn't it work? How can I fix it?

Also, I am getting an Android 6.0 runtime permissions related exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
```

When I try to add the permission to a String array in order to check the permission, Android Studio tells me it can't resolve `Manifest.permission` in the  below  code:

```
new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}
```

Why would it be doing this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

For the first part, you should be using `<uses-permission>` [according the the Android Devlopers site](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html). Try making sure you declare your permissions **directly** under the `<manifest>` tag, not in your `<application>` tag. It's hard to know what your problem is without seeing your entire manifest file. [Check out the link I posted above](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html) for more info on how to declare permissions in your manifest.

In regards to your runtime permissions problem:

> With uses-permissions Cannot resolve that..
>
> new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}
>
> Why?

Make sure you're using `android.Manifest` instead of `my.app.package.Manifest`. A lot of times Android Studio will default to the latter instead of the former.

So, your new line of code would look like:

```
new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
```

Edit: I reformatted my answer.

Edit 2: Be wary of importing `android.Manifest`. It *can* cause issues if you're also importing `my.app.package.Manifest`. Other than that `import android.Manifest` is another valid way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Using andorid.Manifest.permission.X instead of Manifest.permission.X solved this for me, thanks.

Comment: I am new in android so i am not able to understand where i have to put "new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};" this line in the android studio.

Answer (score 122):

change this

`Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

into this

`android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

Answer (score 34):

Try this! Since ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  available in following package so Add:

```
import android.Manifest;
```

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: this kind of solution is better as comment if you are not sure.

Answer (score 10):

Add this ***import android.Manifest;***
[image]

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem where used;

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

where it could not resolve symbol `READ_CONTACTS`.

However on using;

```
import android.Manifest;
```

It started to recognize `READ_CONTACT`

Answer (score 8):

If you have already the **uses.permissions** setup correctly in your manifest file, as already mentioned by hnilsen, just replace your line:

```
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

by this one:

```
 android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

This can solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

if you are working on dynamic permissions and any permission like **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** giving error **"cannot resolve method PERMISSION_NAME"** in this case write you code with permission name and then **rebuild your project** this will **regenerate** the manifest(Manifest.permission) file

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                mapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this before running, make sure you have permission to access..

```
try {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
   dialogGPS(this.getContext()); // lets the user know there is a problem with the gps
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}
```

To this

```
new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}
```

Your problem will be resolved.

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38083495).

Answer (score 0):

```
new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}
```

change it to

```
android.manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

Comment: Hi Jagrit Vishwakarma, do you mean one should remove the `new String[]{` part?

Answer (score -1):

When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on **Manifest**, Android Studio suggests a few options to import. You should choose the one `import android.Manifest;` instead of `import <your.package.name>.Manifest;`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_SELECT_PICTURE);
        return;
    }
```