# Cannot Resolve Symbol ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android, gps, manifest

I have this code

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

In manifest, I have included this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

But I got error `cannot resolve symbol 'ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Its resolved here too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139048/cannot-resolve-manifest-permission-access-fine-location

Answer (score 20):

`import android.Manifest;` since sometimes it uses class manifest

Answer (score 10):

This permission is in android package

```
android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following code:

```
import android.Manifest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this permission in AndroidManife.xml before application tag starts

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```