# Android activity cannot resolve symbol ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to check permission for access to background location.

I have already visited this [Cannot resolve Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139048/cannot-resolve-manifest-permission-access-fine-location)
and I have examined all the provided solutions. None of them solved my issue.

Here is my code in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

and here is how I am trying to check the permission:

```
boolean backgroundLocationPermissionApproved =
       ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
           permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
           == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

I am getting this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol static checkBackGroundLocationPermissions
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: use this library : https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission
its very simple and handles permission perfectly.

Comment: Write the permission like this Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Comment: @EliasFazel I have tried that. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: paste more codes of your activity when you call for checkSelfPermission()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. So I am posting it here in case somebody else has the same problem.

Basically I was trying to ask permission for a background location tracking. It turned out that asking for permission is a requirement only if you have upgraded your app to work with Android 10 (Android Q).
To check if your app needs permission, simply go to build.gradle file and check your targetSdkVersion. If it is anything below 29, like in my case which is 27, then you don't need to check permission for background location tracking.
However, it is a good practice to upgrade your app to work with Android 10 by setting your targetSdkVersion to 29 and upgrading all your dependencies.

To some up this answer, I couldn't get ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION simply because the android.Manifest doesn't support that permission if you have not upgraded your app to sdk 29.
For more information consider visiting the following page: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

NOTE:
As indicated by @LordParsley's comment:

- Changing `compileSdkVersion` (not just `targetSdkVersion`) is needed.

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately you can't find any documentation for this new permission.

Comment: Small note on this that you have to set the `compileSdkVersion` not just the `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: do you know how to do it without change compileSdkVersion?